# Best way to clone form elements jQuery Mobile?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm building a web application with jQuery Mobile and have a form that allows the user to add another row of similar data. Something like this:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type='text' name='item' />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type='checkbox' name='recurring' />
    </td>
    <td> <a href="#" class="add-row">Add</a>

    </td>
</tr>
```

When a user clicks the Add link I am deep cloning the table row and appending it to the table.  It copies all the styling and event handlers.  The issue is of course that all the event handlers are still linked to the original element and don't update the new element. How can I remove these events from the cloned row and bind them again?

Or am I just going about it the wrong way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do bind and unbind this way.

```
$('elemSelector').clone().find('.add-row').unbind('click').click(addRowHandler);
```

My suggestion:

Use delegated event handler instead of just using deepclone to clone the element and performing an `unbind/bind` on the elements. You can do it using `on()`

EX:

In your pageinit

```
      //...

     $('table').on('click', '.add-row', addRowHandler);

      //...
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eV8wB/)**

Basically what you are trying to do here is, instead of attaching the event on the element you attach it on the parent element (table) that exist in DOM at any given point in time so that any newly added (add-row) will have the event available by delegation. So with this you have the event delegated for the element present now and for the future.

See:

**[event-delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)**

***Update***

Based on your late comment, i have anothe r solution using templating.

Simplest approach is to create a template of your row to be cloned everytime, because if you clone the existing row it will clone the existing transformed elements too which can cause issues that you are facing, instead template the row , clone it and append it when required and call `trigger('create')` to apply JQ mobile transitioning on the elements.

```
var template = '<tr><td><input type="text" name="item" /></td><td><label class="checkbox" data-mini="true"><input type="checkbox" name="incomeRecurring[]">Recurring</label></td><td><a href="#" class="add-row">Add</a></td></tr>';

$('table').on('click', '.add-row', function () {
     $('table tbody').append($(template).clone()).trigger('create'); //recreate the elements
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/f9VLE/)**

Comment: Thank you for your answer PSL.  I will try this and see if it indeed solves the issue.  I may need to tell jqm to apply the styling to the newly created element however.  Your demo didn't include all the styling, events etc that jqm adds

Comment: Actually I just added the resources to your fiddle and it seems to work!  Thanks so much, this has been irritating me for days!

Comment: Actually it doesn't work in my application :(  Updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/eV8wB/4/

Comment: @user2535949 Updated the answer with the solution.

Comment: Thanks PSL for your quick reply :)  I was aware I could do this, its just not very dynamic unfortunately. If I change the markup of the html I also have to remember to change it in the javascript.  There doesn't look like there's a nice succinct way to do it.  Thank you muchly for your solutions :)

Comment: @user2535949 you need to go with templating and there is nothing wriong with that many engines uses templating and also it makes sure that you dont copy/clone over non required elements etc.. There is another better way to keep it in html itself, check this http://jsfiddle.net/XmCDV/

Comment: Thanks for the Fiddle PSL.  I think I will go with that solution.  It makes my workflow much simpler :)